# Data Access Layer with Multiple Backends and Different Database Designs

Tags: c#, data-access-layer, backend

I am starting a project and am struggling with the architecture for our data access layer. Basically it will need to interface with multiple backends with different database designs.

I would like a common DAL, which then executes a common function in any backend. The backends have unique code for inserting, updating, etc. So adding an Employee in 1 backend will have different code in another.

I tried the Repository pattern but that just doesn't apply to the situation. I've ended up with just a Factory pattern method, but I will end up creating a Factory for each object. I could maybe only create 1 factory but then the Backend object would have hundred of functions like "SaveEmployee", "SavePlan", etc.

Right now I have the following:

```
DAL
    --> DAL.Backend1
        --> Employee.Save(employee)
        --> Plan.Save(plan)
    --> DAL.Backend2
        --> Employee.Save(employee)
        --> Plan.Save(plan)
```

In the DAL project I have a Factory pattern for each Object, Employee, Plan, to decide which DAL's Object to return and execute against.

I am pretty sure this is not the best architecture for this, so I am wondering if there's a better pattern to use to solve my problem.

Comment: Less going completely dynamic and dynamically building the CRUD statements, you're going to have to have the concrete functionality somewhere. If you don't want it in the database, then I think the route you've gone is the best route.

Comment: I usually tend to the composite pattern.

Comment: Define "different database designs". You mean - one is SQL, one XML, one NoSql? Or do we talk of different relational databases?

Comment: They are all MS SQL Databases, but different table names, stored procedures, etc. But those databases in essence do the same job (business wise).

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, where there may be one or more DALs we need to talk to, depending on the customer (we have a few that require stuff to be registered simultaneously in two separate database systems). The problem is how to manage those calls and deal with any errors. Another issue is keeping the data coupled together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've implemented this functionality on one of our projects. I'm not sure it's the best solution, but so far it's working for us. However, we have a custom DAO layer based on CodeSmith templates that generate the CRUD classes for us. Essentially, we created a singleton which represents a connection broker for all users. When the user logs in, they select the database the want to connect to (though some IP filtering narrows down their options, ideally to 1). The login stores a Connection Token with the associated user and the base class for the generated DAO layer calls the connection broker to retrieve the appropriate connection string. That way anytime a DAO object is called the connection string is gathered before the DAO object attempts to connect to the DB.